# how to find min max of three varirable using only boolean and numerical comparisons, and the abs function

Tags: python, math

i got an assignment that need to find which one is the highest, lowest, or middle

assume that value of three variable x, y, z will be randomly given and we dont know the value.

and we cant use min(), max()

> can use only numerical comparisons, boolean and abs function

i spend so much times try to figure out but still stuck.

this is example one of my code but this doesn't work when y is higest number because of this line

"range_between_middle_max = abs(max_yx - max_zx) + abs(max_zx - max_zy)"

```
x = 23
y = 14
z = 123

range_yx = abs(x - y)
middle_yx = (x + y) / 2
max_yx = middle_yx + (range_yx / 2)


range_zx = abs(x - z)
middle_zx = (x + z) / 2
max_zx = middle_zx + (range_zx / 2)


range_zy = abs(z - y)
middle_zy = (z + y) / 2
max_zy = middle_zy + (range_zy / 2)



range_between_middle_max = abs(max_yx - max_zx) + abs(max_zx - max_zy)
middle = abs(abs(max_yx - max_zx) - max_zy)
highest = middle + range_between_middle_max
lowest = (x+y+z) - (middle + highest)

print(highest)
print(middle)
print(lowest)
```

Comment: How would you do it using a pen and paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can operate comparison results as numbers to avoid using if-else:

```py
xBz = x >= z
yBz = y >= z
xBy = x >= y
zBy = z > y
yBx = y > x
zBx = z > x
max = xBz * xBy * x + yBz * yBx * y + zBy * zBx * z
min = zBx * yBx * x + zBy * xBy * y + yBz * xBz * z
```